# Shadow Button using CardView has to be more

Tags: android, android-cardview, cardview

I need more shadow than the current situation. I've used a CardView, since I assumed this is the better way to add shadow instead of an XML in the drawable directory.

**How it currently is:**
[image]

**How it should be:**
[image]

My Code:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    android:id="@+id/filter_button_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="60dp"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    card_view:cardElevation="16dp">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/filter_linear_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@android:color/white"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TextView/>
        <TextView/>
    </LinearLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Comment: card view show shadow at bottom, you should use custom drawable for that

Comment: best option is to use 9-patch image

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve something like this by **defining a custom shadow** (drawable/shadow.xml):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       android:shape="rectangle">
    <gradient
        android:angle="90"
        android:endColor="@android:color/transparent"
        android:startColor="@android:color/black"/>
</shape>
```

Using it like this:

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">
        <View
            android:layout_width="360dp"
            android:layout_height="24dp"
            android:background="@drawable/shadow"
            />
    <View
        android:layout_width="360dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

So the "shadowView" is on top of the View you want to have your shadow.